# Contour ordering in the Keldysh Formalism

Tags: condensed-matter, greens-functions

I am currently working on some transport problems using the non-equilibrium Green's function techniques.

I am trying to understand the contour ordered intgeral that the Keldysh Formalism uses to define Green's functions.

I am quite sure I understand how the contour ordering works for a single operator:
$$\tilde{T}[e^{i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'H_{h}'(t')}]O_{h}(t)T[e^{-i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'H_{h}'(t')}]=T_{C_{t}}[e^{-i\int_{t_0}^{t}dt'H_{h}'(t')}O_{h}(t)]$$
where $\tilde{T}$ is the anti-time ordering operator, $T$ is the time ordering operator and $T_{C_{t}}$ is the **contour ordering operator** which is defined as placing operators at times that come later in the conour $C_{t}$ left to that of operators at times that come before.

[image]

Now, the way I understand it is that the contour $C_{t}$ provides only a *way* to order the operators so that the terms on the L.H.S and R.H.S are equal. It's not that we are integrating in the complex plane over the contour *itself*.

Usually, $t_0\rightarrow -\infty$.

Moving on to two operators at different times, we arrive at the definition of the Green's function given [here](http://tfp1.physik.uni-freiburg.de/eu_www/Miraflores/):

$$G_{ij}(t,t')=\frac{\langle \Psi_{H}|T_{C_{t,t'}}[c_i(t)c^{\dagger}_{j}(t')]|\Psi_{H}\rangle}{\langle \Psi_{H}|\Psi_{H}\rangle}$$

What I don't understand is how would this give rise to the four different Green's functions,$G^{++}, G^{-+}, G^{+-}, G^{--}$ given in the reference. To my understanding,the thing that we actually measure in other places, the expectation value - $\langle \Psi_{H}|T[c_{iH}(t)c^{\dagger}_{jH}(t')]|\Psi_{H}\rangle$, will upon reducing the two operators to the interaction picture, give two separate contours for the two operators.

I am obviously not getting the motivation behind making four things out of one entity.So, finally, my question is what is going on when I am defining the Green's function? How am I getting four distinct possibilities or rather why am I using four different entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation value in the question,
$$\langle\Psi_{H}|T[c_{iH}c_{jH}^{\dagger}]||\Psi_{H}\rangle$$
is actually the causal Green function $G^{--}_{ij}$.

Let us assume the Hamiltonian: $H=h+H'(t)$

After transforming the operators to the interaction picture and doing some gymnastics, $G^{--}_{ij}$ can be written by choosing the reference time at $t_0=-\infty$ as:
$$G^{--}(1,2)=\langle U_{I}(-\infty,+\infty)U_{I}(\infty, t_1)c_{iI}(t_1)U_{I}(t_1,t_2)c_{jI}^{\dagger}(t_2)U_{I}(t_2,-\infty)\rangle\theta(t_1-t_2)-\langle U_{I}(-\infty,+\infty)U_{I}(\infty, t_2)c^{\dagger}_{jI}(t_2)U_{I}(t_2,t_1)c_{iI}(t_1)U_{I}(t_1,-\infty)\rangle\theta(t_2-t_1)$$

I have left out the bra and the ket because the average could also be taken over an ensemble.

The entity defined above can be conveniently represented by the expression:
$$G^{--}(1,2)=\langle T_{C}[e^{-i\int_{C}H_{I}'(\tau)d\tau}c_{iI}(t_1)c_{jI}^{\dagger}(t_2)]\rangle$$

As in the question, the contour ordering rearranges the operators in a way that times that come later on the contour are to the left of times that come earlier.

[image: $T_C$ is the contour ordering operator as defined in the question.One]

In the image shown here, we are assuming that $t_1 >t_2$, the **main point** is that the two time variables occur in the upper branch(represented by $(-)$) of the contour, and the contour ordering acts on them like a simple *time ordering* operator.

A way to prove this would be by noticing that $\int_{C}$can be broken up into four pieces and then expanding the exponential.

Similarly,$G^{++}$ is the anti-causal Green's function with the usual definition using the anti-time ordering operator.

A similar contour can be constructed for this case except now,contrary to the previous case,both the times of the operators would have to be placed on the lower branch $(+)$ of a contour that would look like this:

[image]

We have assumed here that $t_2>t_1$. In this case, the contour ordering acts like an anti-time ordering operator on the lower branch.

In the same way, the lesser$(G^{-+})$ and the greater$(G^{+-})$ Green's functions are defined using a similar contour with different placements of the operators on the two branches as indicated by their indices.

[This](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/ThomasVeness/journalclub/sources/Rammer.pdf) is an exhaustive review of the whole thing.